# What is the difference between Burning via Data Size over Time Duration

Tags: video, dvd, burning

Assume i have 2 Video Files, both 20 minutes long, both same format. one is 2 GB (File A) and one is 200 MB (File B) because it's been heavily compressed.

Now if i remember correctly i can burn 120 Minutes on a 4.7 GB Disk. that being said if i was to burn the DVD as a Data Disk i could only fit 2 x File A's while i could fix 23 x File B's

But since they are the same duration, i should be able to burn 6 x File A's or B's. So i am wondering, when burning as a DVD as a Video Disk is the size of the file taken into account or would i be able to burn File A 6 times despite it's huge size

Comment: You should be able to test this easily with a cheap DVD-R. The question is, what format are the videos in (i.e. what are the codecs used)? If they're not in standard DVD MPEG format then both will be converted before burning as a video disc, in which case you ought to end up with 6 x As or Bs.